# for loop with multiple conditions

Tags: java, for-loop

I have an array

```
int[] arr = {9,20,-2,-45,23,5,1};
```

I'm sorting it using

```
java.util.Arrays.sort(arr);
```

The for loop:

```
for(int i =0;(i<arr.length) && (arr[i] > 0) ; i++)
```

doesn't seem to work because of the condition `(arr[i] > 0)`. I coudn't think of a reason why this shouldn't work. What's surprising is that the follwing loop works in expected manner :

```
for(int i =0;(i<arr.length) && (arr[i] != 0) ; i++)
```

and

```
for(int i =0;(i<arr.length) && (arr[i] < 0) ; i++)
```

Comment: And what is that expected manner in which those loops should work?

Comment: If you're trying to output the content of your sorted array drop the second criteria and do just: for(int i =0; i<arr.length; i++)

Comment: `i` is 0, `arr[i]` is -45 after sorting, so your condition is `false`, the loop won't execute. What is your question??

Comment: -45 is less than 0. I'm failing to see the question here. Working as intended.

Comment: Thanks guys. For (arr[i] > 0). i expected it to print all the positive numbers in the array, but the base condition itself turns out to be false, so i is not incremented. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Sorry guys. That was a dumb mistake. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`java.util.Arrays.sort(int[] arg);` sorts in ascending order, as a result the first value (`arr[0]`) after sorting would be -45. `for(int i =0;(i<arr.length) && (arr[i] > 0) ; i++)` would be false on the first iteration since `arr[0] == -45`, and therefor `(arr[0] > 0)` is false.)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int[]%29 for why

Comment: I think the first element will be -45 after sorting. But you logic is still correct (+1).

Comment: @mike, just to give you update that after sorting elements will get sorted in ascending order, so in this case it will `-45` and not `-2`.

Comment: Derp. Completely missed the -45. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Once you sort the array, `-45` becomes the first element, so the `> 0` check immediately evaluates to `false`.

On the other hand `< 0` evaluates to `true` for the first two elements, and `!= 0` evaluates to `true` for the entire array.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, after you sort your array, *your loop will never run.*

The condition `arr[i] > 0` is invalid, since the first element you'll encounter would be less than 0.

The condition `arr[i] != 0` would run for as long as you don't have a 0 in your array.

The condition `arr[i] < 0` would run for only the first two elements.

Answer (score 1):

The first loop stops before the first item because `arr[0]` is negative.

If you want to get only positive element in the loop, the correct syntax is :

```
    for (int i = 0; (i < arr.length) ; i++) {
        if (arr[i]> 0) {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @obourgain. This is what i should have done.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.sort()` will sort the given array, by default, according to its `natural order`. For `int` that will mean ascending. Given that, here is how your 3 loops play out:

```
for (int i =0; (i<arr.length) && (arr[i] > 0); i++)
```

When the loop is initialized `i=0` and `arr[0] = -45`. That doesn't pass the second condition in your check, `(arr[i] > 0)`, and the loop is "skipped".

```
for (int i =0; (i<arr.length) && (arr[i] != 0); i++)
```

Because there is no element with the value of `0` in your array `(arr[i] != 0)` always evaluates to `true`. With that out of the way the loop just plugs along through the length of the array.

```
for (int i =0; (i<arr.length) && (arr[i] < 0); i++)
```

This loop should only print the first 2 elements of the array, `arr[0] = -45` and `arr[1] = -2`. Same reasoning as the first loop.

**To Sum Up:**

If you want to print the entire sorted array, the only thing you care about is not running past either end of the array and causing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. So just start at `0` and go until you reach `arr.length`.  You might want to also check out [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5b%5d%29) for `Arrays.sort()`.